# Error during jmeter traffic execution. "Couldn't flush user prefs: java.util.prefs.BackingStoreException: Couldn't get file lock."

Tags: performance, jmeter, traffic

I'm using jmeter to perform traffic performance test.
During traffic execution jmeter returns some errors that increase total execution error.
Can someone help me?

These is the error:

```
summary + 4858 in 00:00:16 = 304.8/s Avg: 481 Min: 9 Max: 4536 Err: 0 (0.00%) Active: 179 
Started: 659 Finished: 480
summary + 12502 in 00:00:30 = 414.9/s Avg: 426 Min: 8 Max: 4147 Err: 0 (0.00%) Active: 178 
Started: 1908 Finished: 1730
summary = 17360 in 00:00:46 = 376.8/s Avg: 441 Min: 8 Max: 4536 Err: 0 (0.00%)
summary + 12432 in 00:00:30 = 416.2/s Avg: 442 Min: 9 Max: 4208 Err: 0 (0.00%) Active: 203 
Started: 3160 Finished: 2957
summary = 29792 in 00:01:16 = 392.3/s Avg: 442 Min: 8 Max: 4536 Err: 0 (0.00%)
Dec 14, 2021 5:11:43 PM java.util.prefs.FileSystemPreferences checkLockFile0ErrorCode
WARNING: Could not lock User prefs. Unix error code 24.
Dec 14, 2021 5:11:43 PM java.util.prefs.FileSystemPreferences syncWorld
WARNING: Couldn't flush user prefs: java.util.prefs.BackingStoreException: Couldn't get file 
lock.
**Dec 14, 2021 5:12:13 PM java.util.prefs.FileSystemPreferences checkLockFile0ErrorCode
WARNING: Could not lock User prefs. Unix error code 24.
Dec 14, 2021 5:12:13 PM java.util.prefs.FileSystemPreferences syncWorld
WARNING: Couldn't flush user prefs: java.util.prefs.BackingStoreException: Couldn't get file 
lock.**
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

From my very limited understanding of C language Unix error 24 stands for ["too many open files"](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/uapi/asm-generic/errno-base.h#L28)

```
#define EMFILE      24  /* Too many open files */
```

You can check the current limit by running [`ulimit -n`](https://ss64.com/bash/ulimit.html) command

If you have superuser permissions you can [ramp-up this limit](https://ss64.com/bash/ulimit.html) according to the number of threads you're using

If you don't have root access - the only solution would be finding another machine and [running your JMeter test in distributed mode](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-perform-distributed-testing-in-jmeter/)